# creating user related user specific content

Tags: mysql, database-design

Should you create a table for each user to contain information on specific content for an account, say favorite articles, interests, ect. User defined lists that would be used to generate useful content using a tag system to define groups of content. Would i be approaching this close to right, or is there a better way. i know u should not define more than one thing in a column, but i also would want the fewest number tables too? is there a way to use a table for all users to store info in such a manner?

Comment: No, I would advice against this. Do more research on normalization. in the meanwhile, start with defining what you need to know from each user. Then determine the common list items, you will soon see that you users have many common factors. However, you could if you want to use an non RDBMS database system instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your the number of tables in your database should not depend on the number of users. Have a table of for the users and another table for preferences with a foreign key to the users table.